# Where is my Emacs install?

Tags: init-file, osx

I want to configure my Emacs install to work with Gmail and I need to find my install location to configure it.

I installed Emacs on my Mac using Homebrew. Where would the install be located it? How can I find it?

Is there any other way to configure Emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, some references:

Official manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html

Some discussion with examples: https://superuser.com/questions/73458/where-is-emacs-file

Brief answer: <kbd>M-:</kbd>`user-init-file` will print in the minibuffer the location of the configuration file which was used when this Emacs version started. Typically, this will be `~/.emacs`, `~/.emacs.el` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

There are several mail user agents (programs to manage emails) available in Emacs. Gnus is the one that comes with Emacs built-in. You can put Gnus-specific configuration in the Emacs init file, or you can put it separately in `~/.gnus` file.  I recommend reading this walk-through, if you will choose to use Gnus as your MUA: https://eschulte.github.io/emacs24-starter-kit/starter-kit-gnus.html . (This is the one I use too). A popular alternative is http://emacswiki.org/emacs/WanderLust but I wouldn't know how to set it up with GMail.

Comment: The link you provided for Wanderlust has some examples for gmail configuration.

Comment: @lawlist I didn't try them myself, so I don't want to make an impression that I know what I'm doing :) I only want to be responsible for Gnus part, if there will be follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the install location to configure Emacs. You do so though a init file in your home directory.

The manual can tell you all you need to know about customizing emacs using the init file (or directory)

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html